# Libgdx on desktop, how to handle disposing when window is closed

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm using libgdx (com.badlogic.gdx.Game and Screens and that stuff) to make a game. I have the following problem: on desktop, when I close the window (from the cross on top), of course the application closes. But I would like to go back to menu screen and dispose there, since I do disposing of resources there (via asset manager). I have buttons for exiting in the game and if exiting is done that way, it's fine. The trouble is that the red cross can be pressed. So how could I handle disposing properly in that case?

On the android version, I catch the back key and handle leaving different parts of the game and the whole game in my own way. And there it works OK.

Another related question I have:

On desktop the application cannot get stopped and then disposed (on it's own, without user explicitly exiting it) like the android version can (the android life cycle), right? So is it a good idea, if I do a temporary save on pause() and restore game state from that on resume(), that I don't restore on desktop (since the restoring isn't a complete restore and I don't want restoring to happen if, on desktop, the window is just minimized (as I noticed, pause()/resume() gets called when minimizing/restoring window )).

Hope this wasn't too unclear :D. I've tried to google for answers but don't seem to find anything. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your problem. How did you implement the dispose method?

Comment: Well, in the game screen dispose() I save the game and dispose the stages I have there. But the problem is that when closing the application from the exit button (on desktop), it doesn't ever go back to the menu screen and the assets won't get disposed (I do disposing of the assets in menu screen's dispose() ).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using the [libgdx life-cycle methods](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/The-life-cycle)

To dispose you should use the `dispose()` method. You don't need to call dispose yourself! It will be called *automatically* when the application gets destroyed, see documentation:

> dispose () Called when the application is destroyed. It is preceded by a call to pause().

So just implement the dispose method in your Screens:

```
@Override
public void dispose () { 
    //your code needs to get added here, like for example:
    stage.dispose();
    texture.dispose();
    //etc..
}
```

Update: Note that dispose() of AppliacationListener gets called automatically, not dispose() of Screen, see comment of Springrbua

Comment: I think just the dispose of Game is called when application is destroyed and by default this just calls hide() on the current screen. So the screens aren't disposed automatically.

Comment: yes the dispose method is called when the application is destroyed. But as you can see the default implementation does not do much. That is why _you_ have to add the code for the disposal there.

Comment: The documentation of `Screen` says, that `dispoes()` for the `Screen` is never called automatically. So you need to `dispose()` the `Screen` in the `hide()` method, or you call `screen.dispose()` in the `dispose()` of your `Game` / `ApplicationListener`

Comment: true. I included that in the answer to make it more clear. @Springrbua

Answer (score 3):

You can call `dispose()`  of your Screen by calling it explicitly from your Game Class `dispose()`  like this

**MyScreen Class:**

```
public class MyScreen implements Screen {
    // Not going to write all other methods that need to be overridden

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // Clear you Screen Resources here
    }

}
```

**MyGame Class:**

```
public class MyGame extends Game {
    // Not going to write all other methods that need to be overridden

    @Override
    public void create() {
        setScreen(new MyScreen());

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // Clear you Screen Explicitly
        getScreen().dispose();

    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, the `Screen` interface contains a `dispose` method. Additionally, the `dispose` method of `Game` can be overridden to dispose of the current screen automatically. However, there is a reason this is not the default. Let's say you have multiple `Screen`s - `Screen1`and `Screen2`. Screen1 was active, then changed the screen to 2. The game is then exited, and the dispose method is called, which calls the *current* screen's dispose method - leaving screen 1 alone.

My preferred method is to have the game keep track of screens set by overriding the setScreen method and adding a Screen[] screens, a boolean[] scrDiss, and an index. When dispose is called on Game, it checks through all screens set, checks if previously disposed, and disposes if not. Additionally, the Screen dispose methods should call a method on the Game that finds it in the array, and marks it disposed. This way, screens can be disposed before the end of the Game, but when Game is disposed, all Screens will be as well.

Answer (score 0):

Call dispose on *all* your screens when your application is disposed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Should I keep a reference to all screens in my Game class? Now I have a reference just to the menu screen. But how can I know if the screen is already disposed or not? Should I introduce a boolean isDisposed to screen class?

Comment: Now I think I got it: I shouldn't call dispose() in my own exitGame() method that I have in the menuScreen. The dispose of the Game will take care of disposing. I guess I'll have to add reference to all the screens I have and check if they are not null and dispose them. If I dispose them earlier, I make the reference in Game null. Does this sound like a good idea?

Comment: You should implement the dispose() method. Take a look at the documentation: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/The-life-cycle @ploosu2

Comment: Yes, I have implemented it now. (The default version just calls hide() on the current screen, which I was using earlier also to decide whether to dispose().) By the way, I read from the link that resume() is only called on Android. Still, my desktop version calls pause() when minimizing the screen and resume(), when restoring. Is this just some sort of debugging thing or what?